# Where to and how to put typedefed structs?

Tags: c, header, struct, typedef

We have a linked list and some typedefed structs:

```
struct _list_node {
    data_object *data;
    struct _temp_list_node *prev;
     struct _temp_list_node *next;
};
typedef struct _list_node list_node;
```

Should we put the typedef in the header (including the struct _listnode?
And then include it both in other files AND in LinkedList.c ?

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the header file if it is part of the interface of the module. If other modules that call functions in LinkedList.c need those definitions put them in the header.

If they are only used within LinkedList.c, keep them private there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's what you should do: put the typedef in the header along with the struct. Then include the header (via #include) into all the files that make use of the struct. Headers are meant to contain declarations, including those of structs. typedef declarations paired to those structs fit in naturally there, and are often expected to be there by someone looking at the code. If you're going to be using the typedef exclusively, you might consider the following syntax, which obviates you from using the `struct` keyword altogether:

```
typedef struct {
    data_object *data;
    struct _temp_list_node *prev;
    struct _temp_list_node *next;
} list_node;
```

I don't particularly care to do the above, but a lot of people do, and it further abstracts away what's inside of list_node, which you might want to do for proper encapsulation.

As a separate note, since you'll be including this header in multiple files, don't forget to use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 1):

generally you'd put it into the header if you need access to it outside of linkedlist.

I tend to only let functions modify the struct though.  So linkedlist.c should have all the functions for dealing with 'list_node' and all those functions should be declared in the .h